# how to fetch real time data from aws server details like cpu ram and hard disk usage

Tags: amazon-web-services

We are running aws xlarge instance and the site has the 2000 con-current users. We need to get the real time server parameters.

Currently we use to get the server parameters using shell and php code but everytime we have to refresh the page to get the details or if we use ajax page and make it load in intervals then the server load goes high.

Is it possible to monitor the real time parameters of the server without using third party tools.

Can anyone give suggestion how should go for this.

Comment: Would it be an option to use alarms so to get notified just when you need it? Like when CPU spikes beyond a certain threshold?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the out of the box AWS service which is provided for FREE - Amazon CloudWatch. The metrics like CPU utilisation, Memory Free, Disk Reads, Disk Writes, Network In, Network Out etc. logged and can be retrieved via API calls.

You do not need to install additional software or agents to enable this data, in fact you don't need to do anything to have this data populated - just launching an Instance would do. By default the data points are collected in 5 min interval, to get even fine grain points you can enable detailed monitoring for additional charge. All the data points are stored for 2 weeks.

More information

https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/details/#amazon-ec2-monitoring
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/CW_Support_For_AWS.html